# Ruby: truncating a long string contained in another string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, truncate

Let `string_a = "I'm a string but this aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa is long."`

How is it possible to detect the `aaaa...aaa` (the part without spaces that is very long) part and truncate it so that the result looks like (the rest of the string should look the same):

```
puts string_a # => "I'm a string but this aaa....aaa is long."
```

I use this method to truncate:

```
  def truncate_string(string_x)
    splits = string_x.scan(/(.{0,9})(.*?)(.{0,9}$)/)[0]
    splits[1] = "..." if splits[1].length > 3
    splits.join
  end
```

So running:

```
puts truncate_string("I'm a very long long long string") # => "I'm a ver...ng string"
```

The problem is detecting the `'aaaa...aaaa'` and apply `truncate_string` to it.

First part of the solution? Detecting strings that are longer than N using regex?

Comment: What do you want to detect, exactly? Any long sequence of repeated characters?

Comment: Detecting a string that is longer or equal to N. N can be any integer.

Comment: You mean a string or a sequence of characters between two whitespaces? To detect if a string has more than N characters you just need to check it's size, which I believe is not your issue...

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention that the string to detect should be without spaces. So it's a sequence of characters between two whitespaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something like

```
string.gsub(/\S{10,}/) { |x| "#{x[0..3]}...#{x[-3..-1]}" }
```

where 10 is the maximum length of a word?

Answer (score 1):

how do you like this?

```
s = "I'm a string but this aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa is long."
s.gsub(/(.* \w{3})\w{5,}(\w{3}.*)/, '\1...\2')
 => "I'm a string but this aaa...aaa is long."
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't work with this example:
`"I'm a very long http://www.exemple.com/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/1:2:3_3_980__eee long long link"`

Comment: You just need to change the \w to a \S. \w means any word character (letter, number, underscore), while \S means any non-whitespace character (so it will include your "/" and ":").

Comment: @Alex learn yourself some regular expressions. it's worth it!